# return type of a function template in C++ as second template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++17

How to implement the template bellow ?

`std::result_of` does not work like that.

I would like to be able to change `std::vector` by something else externally

And I would like to keep `F` and `V` as first in my template

Preferable in C++17

Thanks

```
template <typename F, typename V=vector<result_of<F>>, typename T, typename Ts ...>
auto call (F f, const T & t, const Ts & ... ts) {
  V v;  //  v is a container for values returned from f
  f(....);  // f is a funtion
  ....
  return v;
}
```

Comment: how do you call the function? It's important

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to provide a default template parameter based on the return type of the function without having the function arguments types. I don't know of a good way to do this, but this hack seems to do the trick for your case

```
template <typename F, typename V=bool, typename T, typename... Ts>
auto call(F f, const T& t, const Ts&... ts) {
      using Container = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<bool,
      V>::value,
      std::vector<decltype(f(/*... whatever the args are*/))>,
      V>::type;

      Container c;
     // do stuff...
     return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand what do you want...

But I suppose is something as follows

```
template <template <typename...> class C = std::vector,
          typename F, typename T, typename ... Ts>
auto call (F f, const T & t, const Ts & ... ts)
 {
   C<decltype(f(t))> v;

   (v.emplace_back(t), ..., v.emplace_back(ts));

   return v;
}
```

where the container type is the first template parameter and is defaulted to `std::vector`.

So you can call

```
auto cv = call<std::vector>(foo, '0', '1', '2', '3');
```

or also

```
auto cv = call(foo, '0', '1', '2', '3');
```

But the real problem I see is: how do you insert elements in the container?

I've used `emplace_back()`, thinking at `std::vector`; but if you want pass (by example) `std::set`, you don't find `emplace_back()` but `emplace()`. So do you want also pass the insert method as template parameter?

Anyway, the following is a full working example

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <template <typename...> class C = std::vector,
          typename F, typename T, typename ... Ts>
auto call (F f, const T & t, const Ts & ... ts)
 {
   C<decltype(f(t))> v;

   (v.emplace_back(t), ..., v.emplace_back(ts));

   return v;
}

int foo (char ch)
 { return ch; }

int main()
 {
   auto cv = call(foo, '0', '1', '2', '3');

   for ( auto const & i : cv )
      std::cout << i << ' ';

   std::cout << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. @max66, It might help me somehow, but I would need something that does not depend on the values of t or ts ... I would like to figure out the value of V based only on the value o F.....

In addition: let say we have:....

char f (int, float)....

V would be....

vector<char> by default,.....

but I would like also to be able to replace V by std::string passing it as template argument

Comment: @EdgardLima - isn't clear to me what arguments receive `f()`

Comment: @EdgardLima - I mean... I can I know the type returned from `f()`?

Comment: It wll be used like that   ......   call([](auto x, auto y) { return x + y; }, {1,2,3}, {10,20,30});   .......  my final result will be {11,22,33} .... the return  for "f" may be of any type, .... it will be quite generic .... in this case, f return int, so V will be vector<int> .... but optionally I could use ..... call<function<int>(int,int), deque<int>)[](auto x, auto y) { return x + y; }, {1,2,3}, {10,20,30});

Answer (score 0):

finally i got this

```
template <typename Rt = void, typename F, typename T, typename... Ts>
      auto mapf(F f, const T & t, const Ts & ... ts) {
          auto m = minsize(t, ts...);
          using Vt = decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(*begin(t), *begin(ts)...));
          using V = typename std::conditional<is_same<Rt,void>::value, vector<Vt>, Rt>::type;
          V r;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
          r.resize(m);
          for(auto i = 0u; i < m; i++) {
              auto tuples =  make_tuple(*next(begin(t),i), *next(begin(ts),i)...);
             auto v = apply<tuple<typename T::value_type, typename Ts::value_type ...>>(tuples, forward<F>(f));
              *next(begin(r),i) = move(v);
          }    
          return r;
      }
```

Comment: For my own enlightenment, how is this different from the answer I gave?